# Loading Multiple XML feeds - PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a php file setup to pull through **ONE** XML data feed, What I would like to do is load up to 4 feeds into it and if possible make it select a random item too. Then parse that into an jQuery News Ticker.

My current PHP is as follows...

```
<?php
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load('/feed');
$json = array();

$json['title'] = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
$json['description'] = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
$json['link'] = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;

$items = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('item');

$json['item'] = array();
$i = 0;


foreach($items as $item) {

   $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $description = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $pubDate = $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $guid = $item->getElementsByTagName('guid')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;

   $json['item'][$i++]['title'] = $title;
   $json['item'][$i++]['description'] = $description;
   $json['item'][$i++]['pubdate'] = $pubDate;
   $json['item'][$i++]['guid'] = $guid; 

   echo '<li class="news-item"><a href="#">'.$title.'</a></li>';

}


//echo json_encode($json);


?>
```

How can I modify this to load more than one feed into the file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like this is possible to rewrite this, yeah. Do you have a specific question about the task?

Comment: What I would like to do is load up to 4 feeds into it and if possible make it select a random item too

Comment: .... This site sometimes is useful, sometimes isnt. How can I get a vote down? My question is quite clear nothing short of putting it into bold!

Comment: So you vote it down and vote to close it instead of providing even a little help like Morgan did.. Brilliant! - I've built the PHP already, I just need a little help in how I extend it.

Comment: I'm happy to provide as much help as I can once you tell us which part of the task you are having trouble with. Is your question about  how to build a loop and walk through it? Or is it about calling multiple XML sources one after another? In short, can you clarify where you are  stuck?

Comment: Nothing short of repeating myself... Again! I would like to load in 4 or more feeds into possibly an array and have that load the data into my site. I will worry about the random stuff later

Comment: Again! *What exactly is your programming question?*

Comment: Nope sorry, What you want me to do put it in bold!? *gives up* - I would like to load in more than ONE as I put in bold in my question too. Nothing short of that I dont know what else to ask

Comment: Look, you say you are a web dev and that you work with Zend and CI. From that, one assumes that one knows the basics of the language, and then this question looks *really*  strange and one wonders what the problem is, like I did. Be open about your level of actual knowledge and you'll get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach to doing this is wrapping another loop around the code you have. It's not the cleanest way but will probably suffice for the purpose.

In general, IMO, it's always beneficial to learn the basics of the language first. E.g. [PHP manual on `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

This is roughly what the loop needs to look like:

```
$my_feeds = array("http://.....", "http://.....", "http://.....");

foreach ($my_feeds as $my_feed)
 {
  // This is where your code starts
  $feed = new DOMDocument();
  $feed->load($my_feed); <--------------- notice the variable
  $json = array();

 ... and the rest of the code

 }
```

this will  walk through all the URLs in `$my_feeds`, open the RSS source, fetch all the items from it, and output them.

Comment: Thats the principles I'd like yeah. I need to try convert that $feed variable to a string so that the URL's are 'http://blabla.com' not http://blabla.com as I am getting the error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string

Comment: @Stu ugh, sorry, my bad. Fixed, try again

Comment: Thanks for that @Pekka I then created a function to shuffle the array and it works a treat

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, what you may want to do is turn your code into a function, which you would then run inside a foreach loop for each url (which you could store in an array or other data structure).

Edit: If you don't know much about functions, this tutorial section might help you. http://devzone.zend.com/9/php-101-part-6-functionally-yours/